# How can I change/set the homepage for multiple browsers at once?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, windows-registry

So I have a project that involves me resetting the homepage of about ~70 computers that are in a test group to a new home page.   In the past I've done this via registry, but this time I have to target all browsers rather than just one.   I've been Googling, but it seems like Firefox might not be able to do this easily...

Is there some program / setting that I could save / run once per computer to reset the home-page on the major browsers mentioned above?

Comment: i think you must ask this in http://stackoverflow.com
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043616/programmatically-set-the-default-homepage-for-mozilla-firefox

Comment: Maybe, but this is really more of a sysadmin-style question.  When I wanted to disable zoom via registry I was point here and got:  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ZOOM]
"ZoomDisabled"=dword:00000001

Comment: Well if i want to do something like this i will code something my self using C#
you can go download [Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)

Comment: I could probably whip something up in java or C++ to handle the task, but I feel like that would be over-engineering the issue.

Comment: Well in my idea that will be the best way :)

Comment: @Damien.Bell I think that wouldn't be too difficult in this case, although I'd probably stick with a more scripting-oriented language (like C# or Python).

Comment: @idavid - The fact you want to handle this for multiple browsers sounds like you should write a simple console application that does it and just run across your domain on the computers you push it to on startup.  Furthermore the ability to set the homepage for all thhe mainstream browsers by their registry key is well documented.  **I would agree this is a Stackoverflow question even if you use Powershell to do it.**

Comment: @Ramhound: "Furthermore the ability to set the homepage for all the mainstream browsers by their registry key is well documented" - Besides IE, which mainstream browsers store their homepage settings in the registry?

Comment: Actually, given that you're trying to _administer a large number of computers_, [SF] would actually be the best fit, although I see no problem with having it here on SU if you prefer. Look up documentation on the user.js file, for a start.

Comment: @Karan - It was a more general statement.  I did a quick Google search and was able to find a script for both Firefox and Chrome without much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to need to do this more than once?

If so, I would change them (individually this time) to a page you create which redirects to the homepage you want.  Then any future changes would just take editing the address on your pass-through page.